# Seeking contour data for Oregon?

Tags: data, contour, united-states

Does anyone know where I can find good contour layers for Oregon?

I do not have spatial analyst, so I can not make my own.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.oregongeology.org?

Comment: If you are seeking open data, even when it is spatial, then I think the best place to research/ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: There are open source tools which will accomplish this if you have a DEM.  Have you tried QGIS? No license required.

Comment: I have been looking around on oregongeology.org and have not found any  contours.  I have barely looked at QGIS.  I could really use some good 20ft interval contours for Oregon. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can make you own with a really straightforward workflow and a couple of free gdal tools

1) download the SRTM data from http://dwtkns.com/srtm/

2) merge multiple tifs into one

```
gdal_merge.py -a_nodata -32768 -o output.tif tiff1.tiff tiff2.tiff ..
```

3) make your own contours

```
gdal_contour -a elevation -i 10 output.tif oregan.shp
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Oregon Spatial Data Library](http://spatialdata.oregonexplorer.info/geoportal/catalog/search/search.page) (search for contour) has 100ft & 500ft contours available as shape files. They are split up into 9 sections to keep the sizes down.

Comment: I want like a 40ft or 20ft countour interval. a usgs contour layer that they use would be super cool. yuh know how the usgs has all the maps. and they have contours. if i could get all those contours in a line type shapefile that would be great. lookin all smooth and clean. not all jenky like a derived layer